# Trying to pass form from generic.FormView to generic.DetailView

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django and it's just a test for further model. I'm trying to pass a form from generic.FormView to generic.DetailView, and exhibit the datas inserted in the previous HTML (associated with the FormView) to another HTML (associated with the DetailView). I've thought it probably a problem with the link between the view.py and urls.py. The codes are:

views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'dutos/index.html'
    form_class = GetDate
    success_url = 'dutos/detail.html'

    #def form_valid(self, form):                                   
       #return HttpResponse(self.success_url)
       #return super.form_valid(form)

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Dutos
    template_name = 'dutos/detail.html'
```

forms.py

```
class GetDate(forms.Form):
    dateDataInicial = forms.DateTimeField(label='dataInicial', initial=datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), required=False)
    dateDataFinal = forms.DateTimeField(label='dataFinal', initial=datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), required=False)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('detail/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Teste HTML</h1>
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="/detail/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.dateDataInicial.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ form.dateDataInicial }} Data Inicial: </label>
                    {{ form.dateDataInicial }}
                </div>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.dateDataFinal.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ form.dateDataFinal }} Data Final: </label>
                    {{ form.dateDataFinal }}
                </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

detail.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Template HTML</h1>
{{form.cleaned_data['dateDataInicial']}}
{{form.cleaned_data['dateDataFinal']}}

</body>
</html>
```

I've already change the "{{form.cleaned_data['dateDataInicial']}}" to "form.dateDataInicial", or just cleaned everything and put "Test" to exhibit a simples HTML. I'm getting HTTP Error 405.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I'm getting HTTP 405. I wil update de question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Daniel and his code, I figured out the modifications that lead to my needs. I've changed the genericView of DetailView from "generic.DetailView" to "generic.ListView". When it was made another problem appeared. To pass "datetime" through JSON, it convert to string format and all the date was being treated as string, so I lost the possibility to show the two dates in separated fields in detail.html. To overcome this problem, I adapted the solution proposed to Daniel, and divided the field in two so I can get it by form.cleaned_data and converted it into string, and now I don't need to worry about JSON serializing a "datetime".

views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'dutos/index.html'
    form_class = GetDate
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detail')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #self.request.session['dates'] = json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        self.request.session['dateInicial'] = str(form.cleaned_data['dateDataInicial'])
        self.request.session['dateFinal'] = str(form.cleaned_data['dateDataFinal'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DetailView(generic.ListView):
    model = Dutos
    template_name = 'dutos/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #kwargs['dates'] = self.request.session.pop('dates', {})
        kwargs['dateInicial'] = self.request.session.pop('dateInicial', {})
        kwargs['dateFinal'] = self.request.session.pop('dateFinal', {})
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

index.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.dateDataInicial.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ form.dateDataInicial }} Data Inicial: </label>
                    {{ form.dateDataInicial }}
                </div>
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.dateDataFinal.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ form.dateDataFinal }} Data Final: </label>
                    {{ form.dateDataFinal }}
                </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

detail.html:

```
<body>

<h1>Detalhes</h1>

{{ dateFinal }}
<br>
{{ dateInicial }}

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really quite a lot wrong with the code you've posted.

You're getting 405 because the form in your index template attempts to post directly to the detail URL, which is not set up to accept POST requests. An additional problem with doing this is that the form will not be validated, because the validation is supposed to happen in the IndexView, not the DetailView. Plus, the DetailView does not know anything about the form, so `form.cleaned_data` would not exist in the template context; and, Django template syntax does not support dictionary lookup via square brackets, so `{{ form.cleaned_data['dateDataInicial'] }}` would not work.

In order for validation to work you need to submit the form back to IndexView, which will then redirect to the detail view. (Another issue with your code is that success_url should be a URL, not a template path.) The problem then becomes how to get the data from one view to the other; the session is a good way to do that. So:

```
class IndexView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'dutos/index.html'
    form_class = GetDate
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detail')

    def form_valid(self, form):                                   
       self.request.session['dates'] = form.cleaned_data
       return super.form_valid(form)
```

change the form tag in index.html:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
```

the detail view:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Dutos
    template_name = 'dutos/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['dates'] = self.request.session.pop('dates', {})
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

and in detail.html:

```
{{ dates.dateDataInicial }}
{{ dates.dateDataFinal }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've followed the Form Example provided by Django and tried to adapt it to my needs. I've tried your suggestion, but still getting HTTP Error 405. I understood your points and applied the changes. Your answer raised a doubt about the difference between "template_name" and "succes_url" and why the first one I can pass a template path and the second one the URL?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the action value in the form tag - edited. As to the difference between those attributes, well one is a template and one is a URL...

Comment: Thanks again, you are being very helpful! I changed the "action" (I don't need to specify the action because de Django do it through view.py and url.py, right?). I still got a HTTP Error 405, but I saw that it would be "super().form_valid(form)" in IndexView. So, I changed it and didn't get it again. Now the error is the follow:

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

I will update the question with form.py. But I use a forms.DateTimeField.

Comment: Changing to "self.request.session['dates'] = json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)" correct such problem. I'm getting "Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.", but I'm not passing a PK. In the future I will get these dates and pass a DB Filter, and probably get the PK that it's asking. I wil try to figure out the slug.

Comment: Changing the detail view to "class DetailView(generic.ListView):", I don't get such error and can access the page detail.html, but de information of "dates" aren't shown.

Comment: If I put just {{ dates }} in detail.html, it exhibit, but it's now a string, not a date anymore. I though it would be a dictionary. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid this.

Comment: I did it! Thanks for your help! I will update the modifications =)